# Converting an Object list to a Queue

Tags: java, list, object, queue

How do I convert a List of objects to a Queue and still be able to access their variables?

First I have a main class that creates instance classes of ClassTwo and gives them a unique ID (just hard coded it for the example)

```
public class ClassOne
{
    static List<ClassTwo> processList = new ArrayList<ClassTwo>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        processList.add(new Process(1));
        processList.add(new Process(2));
        processList.add(new Process(3));
    }
}
```

ClassTwo:

```
public class ClassTwo
{
    int id;

    public ClassTwo(int tempID)
    {
        id = tempID;
    }
}
```

How would I convert my List to a Queue so that I can still access each object's ID in class one?
I tried something like:

```
public class ClassOne
{
    static List<Process> processList = new ArrayList<Process>();
    public static Queue<Object> processQueue = new LinkedList<Object>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        processList.add(new Process(1));
        processList.add(new Process(2));
        processList.add(new Process(3));

        ConvertToQueue();
    }

    ConvertToQueue(List<Process> process)
    {
        //covert here..
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure exactly how to then convert it to a Queue, so i can still call variable 'id' from each ClassTwo object. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you expand your code to show where you are having a problem accessing the id variable?

Comment: Your code is suspect.  In `ClassOne` you are adding `Process` objects to a `List<ClassTwo>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
Queue<Process> queue = new LinkedList<>(processList);
```

When you make this, you can still access to every element of the list, because they are all the same instances.